# Not getting expected NSComparison value

Tags: objective-c, string, search, string-comparison

I am trying to do a filter by comparing a value ('stringToCompare') I have in a list and the search text entered by the user ('searchText'). The code snippet as below.

```
NSComparisonResult result = [stringToCompare compare:searchText options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch) range:NSMakeRange(0, [searchText length])];
NSLog(@"Search text: %@", searchText);
NSLog(@"string to compare: %@", stringToCompare);
NSLog(@"result: %i", result);
NSLog(@"NSOrderedsame: %i", NSOrderedSame);
if (result == NSOrderedSame)
{
   [self.filteredListContent addObject:genericObj];
}
```

However, as can be seen in the NSLog results below, I can't seem to be able to get the expected result. In this case, I am expecting the result to be '0', since the search text 'Xot' can be found as part of 'stringToCompare'. What am I missing here?

```
2012-01-02 05:13:59.184 onethingaday[5815:707] search text: Xot
2012-01-02 05:13:59.185 onethingaday[5815:707] string to compare: One exotic place you got laid in before. How was it?
2012-01-02 05:13:59.188 onethingaday[5815:707] result: -1
2012-01-02 05:13:59.188 onethingaday[5815:707] NSOrderedsame: 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing entire strings, not looking for occurences. Try this:

```
NSRange r = [stringToCompare rangeOfString:searchText
                             options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

if ( r.location != NSNotFound )
{
    NSLog(@"String found at position: %d",r.location);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`-compare:` doesn't search for substrings, it compares the full string within the range. You're getting the expected result, showing you how the string 'Xot' compares to the full string 'One exotic place you got laid in before. How was it?'.